# Dock for wayland

Tags: wayland, dock

I use cairo-dock and sometimes plank on x11. It is time to migrate from the veteran Windowing system -x11- to Wayland, but I cant find a suitable dock(other than dash to dock)

The dock I'm looking for:

- zoom effect
- lightweight

Ubuntu 20.04.2
Gnome 3.36.8
WM - Mutter

Comment: ubuntu 20.04.2 , gnome 3.36.8 , wm- mutter

Comment: Latte dock supports wayland. You might have better luck with it if you use the latest version, which is not necessarily what is offered in the Ubuntu repo.